# Validate the form in php

Tags: php, validation

I have a form in php and i need to validate the form. So i tried these code, but am not getting any validation message. Nothing is being displayed. What is the error that i am getting

```
<form class="" method="post" action="">
<div class ="col-md-3" style="clear:both;">
            <label style="font-size:12px;"> Your Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="AS_Name" name="AS_Name" />
            <span style="font-size:12px; color:red;"> <?php echo $nameError; ?> </span>
            </div>
    <input  id="AstroSend" type="submit" Value="Send" name="submit" />
   </form>

<?php
 $nameError ="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if (empty($_POST["AS_Name"]))
    {   

    $nameError = "Name is required";

    } 
else 
    {

    $name = test_input($_POST["AS_Name"]);
    // check name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) 
    {
    $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
    } ?>
```

If i echo inside `if` loop then its displaying the message. But i want that validation message in the `span` itself.

Comment: Have you tried $_POST to see if the form is beng posted

Comment: yes its posted, i am able to enter the `if` loop and i can echo the message there

Comment: move the php code into top

Comment: i tried moving php to top. But when i click submit the form will dissapear

Comment: You open a bracket after `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` but you never close it. Learn how to format code. Simply use your tabulator as you should, and you would see this errors after 2 seconds.

Comment: @Twinfriends its just a code snippet, i haven't added the entire code

Comment: Can't know that. Anyways, hope you closed the bracket at another place later.Independent of your problem, i really recommend you to learn how to format code. It doesnt matter if the bracket is closed or not, the code would be much easier to read if you format it correct.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the validation above the html not below :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes

```
<?php
 $nameError ="";
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 {
   if (empty($_POST["AS_Name"]))
   {   
    $nameError = "Name is required";
   }

  else 
 {

  $name = test_input($_POST["AS_Name"]);
// check name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) 
     {
       $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
     }
   } 
  }
?>

<form class="" method="post" action="">
<div class ="col-md-3" style="clear:both;">
        <label style="font-size:12px;"> Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="AS_Name" name="AS_Name" />
        <span style="font-size:12px; color:red;"> <?php echo $nameError;?> </span>
          </div>
       <input  id="AstroSend" type="submit" Value="Send" name="submit" />
       </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your the else is placed wrong @coder.

**I works fine for me**

**NewBie can u plz check this**

```
<?php
$nameError ="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

{

```
if (empty($_POST["AS_Name"]))
{   
$nameError = "Name is required";
```

}
else
{
$name = $_POST["AS_Name"];

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
```

{

```
$nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
```

}

```
}
```

}

```
?>
<form class="" method="post" action="">

<div class ="col-md-3" style="clear:both;">
            <label style="font-size:12px;"> Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="AS_Name" name="AS_Name" />
        <span style="font-size:12px; color:red;"> <?php echo $nameError;?> </span>

</div>
<input  id="AstroSend" type="submit" Value="Send" name="submit" />
   </form>
```